# CodeIgniter routing with app ID's and entry ID's

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2

I'm new to CodeIgniter and going to be using it for building a sort of reusable application with multiple instances of an application. For example, each instance of the application will have an id "12345", and inside that instance, there will be entry IDs of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc.

to do this, I think I will want to be able to using Routing to set up something like:

http://example.com/12345/Entry/Details/1

Where this URI will go to the Details page of the Entry of ID=1, inside application ID 12345. This would be a different group of entries from a url of, say, /12346/Entry/Details/1. Is this a routing rule that needs to be set up, and if so, can someone please provide an example of how this could be configured, and then how I would be able to use 12345, and 1, inside of the function. Thanks so much for your help, in advance.

Comment: What is an "application" in this context?

Comment: It's esesntially a photo voting contest, but we want to be able to re-use it multiple times so we create a "contest" which I think i called "application" and that contest would have an ID. Inside each contest, all of the photos that we would be voting on would have their own ID so for example: http://example.com/{contestID}/{class}/{function}/{photoID}

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that you route your urls like this:

```
$route['(:any)/{controller_name}/(:any)/(:any)'] = '{controller_name}/$2/$3/$1';
```

so that the last parameter for the function is always the id of the app (12345/12346). Doing this means that your Entry controller functions will look like this:

```
class Entry extends CI_Controller
{
   function Details(var1, var2, ..., varn, app_id){}

   function Someother_Function (var 1, app_id){}
}
```

you will also need to add a route for functions that don't have anything but the app_id:

```
$route['(:any)/{controller_name}/(:any)'] = '{controller_name}/$2/$1'; //This may work for everything.
```

I hope this is what you we're asking...

Edit:

If you are only going to be using numbers you could use `(:num)` instead of `(:any)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a routing like that by adding this rule to the `application/config/routes.php` file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "yourdefaultcontroller";
$route['404_ovverride'] = "";
// custom route down here:
$route['(:num)/entry/details/(:num)'] = "entry/details/$1/$2",
```

of course assuming your URI to be like the example.

In your controller "Entry" you'll have a method "details" which takes 2 parameters, `$contestID` and `$photoID`, where `$contestID` is the unique instance you're assigning, while `$photoID` is the other (assumed) variable of your url (last segment).

```
class Entry extends CI_Controller(
{
    function details {$contestID, $photoID)
    { //do your codeZ here }
}
```

See [URI routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) for more info on that. You might also want to consider the `__remap()` overriding function, in case.